# Unable to restore nuget/nexus packages for .netcore and .netframework in same solutions from Jenkins

Tags: .net-core, nuget, jenkins-groovy

In my solution, I have .NET Core and .NET Framework projects. I am facing the below error (which is a .NET Core project) while compiling the solution through Jenkins:

> error NETSDK1064: Package IBM.Data.DB2.Core, version 1.3.0.100 was not
>   found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise,
>   NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have
>   been due to maximum path length restrictions.

Comment: Try downloading it manually here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core/

Comment: If that does work, next try to use dotnet cli to install the package manually. Does that work? dotnet add package IBM.Data.DB2.Core --version 1.3.0.100

Answer (score 0):

The Error Message is pretty self-explanatory. Try to restore the package by either right clicking on the solution and selecting "Restore Nuget Packages" in your IDE, or run the below command in the package manager console.

```
nuget restore YourSolution.sln
```

Alternatively, you can also install the package using the below command

```
Install-Package IBM.Data.DB2.Core -Version 1.3.0.100
```

Check for any error messages while restoring or installing packages, in case there are any file path issues.

Comment: I am facing the issues in the Jenkins pipeline script. In ide able to build the solution without any issues